# how do I fix this negative lookbehind regex?

Tags: php, regex, actionscript

I want to capture only `136.50` in the following

```
   $136.50 (was $195.00)
```

I'm trying to use a negative lookbehind in order not to group a price if it is preceded by another price. This is what I have:

`(?<!\$.+)\$(?<price>[\d.,]+)`

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I think the problem might be that I can't use a variable length string inside a lookaround, but I'm not sure how to construct the regex without one.

EDIT: There will sometimes be only one price, in which case I want to group that price. This is why I did not use a positive lookahead to confirm a price is the first price.

Comment: are there other possible formats or is this format the only occurence?

Comment: Why don't you just go for the first price?

Comment: @bukfixart either there will be only one price, or there will be two prices in the format listed, of which I will always want the first

Comment: Negative lookbehind is one area where different languages/regex-engines behave differently; so, if you want someone to tell you what you're doing wrong, you need to indicate what language/tool you're using. (Actually, you *always* need to do that. The `regex` tag should *never* stand alone. But in this case, especially.)

Comment: @owlstead I should have mentioned that sometimes there will only be one price, so I can't use the logic 'get the price as long as it's the first price of more than one'.

Comment: @ruakh at the moment I am just trying to get it to work on regexr.com. I'll be implementing it in PHP5, whatever engine that uses.

Comment: I don't know why you're using an ActionScript tool to debug a PHP regex, but O.K.; I've updated your question to indicate both.

Comment: I don't get it. The regular expression to get one price simply gets the first price if there are multiple, or no match at all. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @ruakh I wasn't aware it made a difference. What would be a better tool?

Comment: @jela: PHP5. (You can run `php` as a command-line program.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use negative look-behind, just take the first price (in the first group, and possibly the second group if there are fractions). Something like this maybe?

```
/^.*?\$([\d,]+)(\.\d\d)?/
```

Comment: I used an one line PERL regexp checker, you may have to remove the slashes from the start and the end...

Comment: thanks this does make more sense than my original method, although I'm still curious whether it is possible to do it that way.

Comment: It's likely. It may require a lot of back tracking though, and in this case it makes not a lot of sense. Regular expressions are better at moving forward :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I think you should take the first price, too:

this should match all prices, incl. koma in thousands, like this one from owlstead
`/^.*?\$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?).*$/`

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
/(\$\d*.\d*)(?!.\1)/
```

This will match the first group and not followed by the same group